# Grid of square photos from URLs Windows Phone 7 using WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7.1

I have a web service that returns about 100 photos and I would like to display all in a 3xN grid on Windows Phone 7.

I have tried the WrapPanel and it works, but for only a few images.. Anything more, and I run out of memory and debugging halts.

Code:

```
<ListBox Height="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="screenshotsListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding}"
                Margin="0"
                Height="110"
                Width="110"
                CacheMode="BitMapCache"
                Stretch="UniformToFill"
                Grid.Row="0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I place all my images in a string array and then bind it to the listBox.

Is there anything that I can do to display a grid of photos downloaded from a web service without eating all the memory?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend profiling the code to identify what the actual cause of the memory usage is but I'd guess that you're probably [down]loading images that are much larger than you need if you're only displaying them as a 110x110px version. Even if you're showing them stretched (shrunk) to a smaller size the full image is loaded into memory. If they're large images the memory use will mount up very quickly.

There are some useful tips relating to images and memory at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For now, I won't show the images in a grid until I get more experience with c#. My new problem is to decode the string Array of URI's and find back some way to bind it to a listBox.